How do I copy Pine script error messages?
It's great the way the Pine editor points out your errors and gives a detailed explanation.  I am using AI to write my back testing pine scripts, so it would be great if i could copy the error explanation to paste to AI to correct the error.  However, it wont let you copy the error message.  Is there any way to copy the error message?
I've tried copying the error messages, but it won't let me.

First open the console

Select and copy message

